# DelegateModelGroup filtering DelegateModel

Tags: qml, kde-plasma

Below is the `DelegateModel` I am using to filter a `ListModel`.I have used five `DelegateModelGroup`'s.The filtering is working for `visible` , `folder` and `falsie` `DeleagteModelGroup`.Now i want to implement a new `DelegateModelGroup`, `visibility` with which i want to be visible only the model items that have visibility role `false`.I tried a lot examples but I had not have  the desired result.How can I configure the update `function` so I can filter the results to `visibility` role?

`visible` `DelegateModelGroup` is filtered for  `false`.

`folder` `DelegateModelGroup` is filtering the items if `folder` role is empty string or not.

`falsie` `DeleagetModelGroup` filters the items so they displayed in pages of 35 items.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQml.Models 2.4

DelegateModel {
    property string roleThree
    property string roleTwo
    property string role
    property int from: 0
    property int to: 10

    onRoleChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
    onFromChanged: Qt.callLater(update)
    onToChanged: Qt.callLater(update)

    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: newItems
            name: "new"
            includeByDefault: true
            onCountChanged:{
                 Qt.callLater(update)
            }
        },

        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
            includeByDefault: false
        },

        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: folderItems
            name: "folder"
            includeByDefault: false
        },

        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibilityItems
            name: "visibility"
            includeByDefault: false
        },

        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: falsieItems
            name: "falsie"
            includeByDefault: false
        }
    ]

    filterOnGroup: "falsie"

    function update() {
        newItems.setGroups(0, newItems.count, [ "new" ] );
                    for (let i = 0; i < newItems.count; i++) {
                        let item = newItems.get(i).model;
                        let visible = item[role] === false ;
                        let folder = item[roleTwo] !== "";
                        let visibility = item[roleThree] ===false;
                    if (!visible && !folder && visibility) continue;
                newItems.setGroups(i, 1, [ "new", "visible" ]);
                visibleItems.setGroups(i, 1, [ "visible","folder"]);

                }
        visibleItems.setGroups(from, to - from , ["visible","falsie"]);
    }
     Component.onCompleted: Qt.callLater(update)

}
```

For any question fill free to comment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the pattern I've used for DelegateModelGroup.

I tend to have "all" which is a master list of all items, "new" which is a list of incoming items, and then DelegateModelGroups for your business rules.

I have two functions

- invalidate() - which pushes everything back into the "new" group for processing
- updateNew() - which pulls an item from the "new" group, 1 item at a time, for filtering

The reason why we are processing the newItems from count-1 backward to 0 is every item being processed will get removed from the newItems list. If we went in ascending order it messes up the for loop and it processes every second record instead of every record. So, by processing it in descending order, we remove items from the end and get to process every item.

```
DelegateModelGroup {
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: newItems
            name: "new"
            includeByDefault: true
            onChanged: Qt.callLater(updateNew)
        },
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "visible" }
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "folder" }
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "visibility" }
        DelegateModelGroup { name: "falsie" }
    ]

    filterOnGroup: "visible"
    function invalidate() {
        allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, ["all","new"]);
    }
    function updateNew() {
        if (!newItems.count) return;
        for (let index = newItems.count-1; index >= 0; index--) {
            let item = newItems.get(index).model;
            let grps = [ "all" ];
            if (item[role] === false) grps.push("visible");
            if (item[rowTwo] !== "") grps.push("folder");
            if (item[roleThree] === false) grps.push("visibility");
            newItems.setGroups(index, 1, grps);
        }
    }
}
```

[EDIT]

In the following example, I have created `FilterDelegateModel.qml`

```
// FilterDelegateModel.qml
DelegateModel {
    property string role
    property string filter
    property double from
    property double to
    property bool invert
    property int page
    property int pageSize
    //...
}
```

which handles both strings (for indexOf searches) and numbers (for from...to range). I made `role`, `filter`, `from`, `to`, `invert`, `page` and `pageSize` as configurable inputs, which, when changed, will cause the `"visible"` and `"page"` DelegateModelGroups to refresh.

`role` can be `"country"`, `"city"`, or `"population"`. If it's the first two, it will limit the results by `"filter"` using `indexOf()`. If you set it to `"population"` it will use `"from"` and `"to"` to limit your results by range. The results will appear in the `"visible"` DelegateModelGroup.

`page` and `pageSize` is used to further filter the results by what results is visible on the current page. These result will appear in the `"page"` DelegateModelGroup.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Label { text: "Role" }
        ComboBox { id: roleCombo; model: [ "country", "city", "population" ] }
        ColumnLayout {
            visible: roleCombo.currentText.match(/country|city/)
            Label { text: "Search" }
            TextField { id: search }
        }
        ColumnLayout {
            visible: roleCombo.currentText === 'population'
            Label { text: "Range %1 to %2".arg(range.first.value).arg(range.second.value) }
            RangeSlider { id: range; from: 0; to: 2000; stepSize: 10; first.value: 0; second.value: 2000 }
        }
        CheckBox { id: chkInvert; text: "Invert" }
        Label { text: "Page" }
        ComboBox { id: pageCombo; model: ["1","2","3","4","5"] }
        Label { text: "Cities (count:%1 of %2)"
                    .arg(filterDelegateModel.pageCount)
                    .arg(filterDelegateModel.visibleCount) }
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            clip: true
            header: RowLayout {
                width: ListView.view.width
                Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 30; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: "Index" }
                Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: "Country" }
                Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: "City"
 }
                Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 70; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: "Population" }
            }
            model: FilterDelegateModel {
                id: filterDelegateModel
                model: Cities { }
                role: roleCombo.currentText
                filter: search.text
                invert: chkInvert.checked
                from: range.first.value
                to: range.second.value
                page: pageCombo.currentIndex
                delegate: RowLayout {
                    width: ListView.view.width
                    Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 30; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: DelegateModel.visibleIndex + 1 }
                    Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: model.country }
                    Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 100; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: model.city }
                    Text { Layout.preferredWidth: 70; Layout.fillWidth: true; text: model.population.toFixed(1) }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// FilterDelegateModel.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQml.Models
DelegateModel {
    property string role
    onRoleChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    property string filter
    onFilterChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    property double from: 0
    onFromChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    property double to: 1.0
    onToChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    property bool invert: false
    onInvertChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    property int page: 0
    onPageChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    property int pageSize: 10
    onPageSizeChanged: Qt.callLater(invalidate)
    readonly property alias visibleCount: visibleItems.count
    readonly property alias pageCount: pageItems.count
    groups: [
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: allItems
            name: "all"
            includeByDefault: true
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: newItems
            name: "new"
            includeByDefault: true
            onChanged: Qt.callLater(updateNew)
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: visibleItems
            name: "visible"
            onChanged: Qt.callLater(updatePage)
        },
        DelegateModelGroup {
            id: pageItems
            name: "page"
        }
    ]
    filterOnGroup: "page"
    function invalidate() {
        allItems.setGroups(0, allItems.count, [ "all","new" ] );
    }
    function updateNew() {
        for (let index = newItems.count-1; index >= 0; index--) {
            let item = newItems.get(index);
            let groups = ["all"];
            let visible = true;
            if (role) {
                let value = item.model[role];
                switch (typeof(value)) {
                case 'string':
                    visible = !filter || value.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
                    break;
                case 'number':
                    visible = value >= from && value <= to;
                    break;
                }           
            }
            if (invert) visible = !visible;
            if (visible) groups.push("visible");
            newItems.setGroups(index, 1, groups);
        }
    }
    function updatePage() {
        let pageStart = page * pageSize;
        let pageEnd = pageStart + pageSize;
        if (pageStart < 0) pageStart = 0;
        if (pageStart >= visibleItems.count) return;
        if (pageEnd > visibleItems.count) pageEnd = visibleItems.count;
        visibleItems.setGroups(pageStart, pageEnd-pageStart, ["all", "visible", "page"] );
    }
}

// Cities.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
ListModel {
    property var cities: `Afghanistan,Kabul,39835428
Argentina,Buenos Aires,45993511
Australia,Canberra,25766340
Bangladesh,Dhaka,166303498
Brazil,Brasília,213993437
Canada,Ottawa,37742154
China,Beijing,1444216107
Colombia,Bogotá,51107063
Czech Republic,Prague,10708981
Egypt,Cairo,104258327
France,Paris,65480710
Germany,Berlin,83190556
Greece,Athens,10715549
India,New Delhi,1393409038
Indonesia,Jakarta,273523615
Iran,Tehran,83290141
Italy,Rome,60550075
Japan,Tokyo,125960000
Mexico,Mexico City,129163276
Netherlands,Amsterdam,17141544
Nigeria,Abuja,214028302
Pakistan,Islamabad,233500636
Peru,Lima,33405000
Philippines,Manila,111046913
Poland,Warsaw,38028278
Portugal,Lisbon,10191409
Russia,Moscow,146599183
Saudi Arabia,Riyadh,35541063
South Africa,Pretoria,61622110
South Korea,Seoul,51780579
Spain,Madrid,46723749
Sri Lanka,Colombo,21413249
Sweden,Stockholm,10171524
Switzerland,Bern,8741992
Thailand,Bangkok,69799978
Turkey,Ankara,85042739
Ukraine,Kyiv,44622516
United Kingdom,London,66647112
United States,Washington D.C.,332915073
Vietnam,Hanoi,97338579`.split(/\n/).map(c => c.split(/,/))
    Component.onCompleted: {
        for (let c of cities) append( { "country":c[0], "city":c[1], "population":c[2]/1000000 } )
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Yes.This example is better than mine but  visibility role, in my application ,continuous not to hide items.I mean items with visibility false continuous to be visible.

Comment: Rather than having multiple DelegateModelGroup(s), I've decided to make `role`, `filter`, `from`, `to` configurable in the DelegateModel. So, you can property bind and switch the role from a `string` to `number` field and adjust accordingly.

Comment: ok.This is better than the old one.But how to configure role,  from , to , so I can display only items with visibility true and display the items in groups of 35 in each page in 6 pages?

Comment: I updated the example to implement `"page"` for displaying a window into the search results which you can use for different pages.